# Get JSON object in LIstBox

Tags: asp.net, json, listbox

I have a JSON object which has name, address, phon number, etc. How to populate these data in a ListBox in ASP.NET?
i have to deserialize using javascript serializer and how to insert into a ListBox?

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery then you can try [.appendTo() function](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)